# Updating records in a binary file with C++

Tags: c++, binary, fileoutputstream

I encountered a problem and my current knowledge of C++ is not enough to solve it. I looked for the answer in books of Stroustrup, but a full understanding of what I'm doing wrong for me not now.

So the essence.

I write to the file:

```
int i = 1;
int j = 2;
ofstream ofs("file", ios::binary);
ofs.write(as_bytes(i), sizeof(int));
ofs.write(as_bytes(j), sizeof(int));
```

After that, I need to update the second value:

```
int j = 10;
ofstream ofs("file", ios::binary);
ofs.seekp(4, ios::beg);
ofs.write(as_bytes(j), sizeof(int));
```

And when I try to read the file:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
ifstream ifs("file", ios::binary);
ifs.read(as_bytes(i), sizeof(int));
ifs.read(as_bytes(j), sizeof(int));
cout << i << ' ' << j << endl;
```

It turns out that I lose the first value. What am I doing wrong? Why did it disappear?

Comment: Do you remember to close the file after having written to it?

Comment: It seems to me that this should not affect the result. However, the code is run separately - that is, recorded first, then updated, then started to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the file will be truncated (`ios:trunc`, i.e. the content is lost upon opening the file for writing).

For the second write operation explicitly add the flags `ios:in` AND `ios:out` despite the fact you're writing only. So essentially I'd use the following:

```
ofstream ofs("file", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out | ios::ate);
```

This should open the file with the stream/file pointer being at the end of the file (`ios::ate` might be optional though).